# VLC turns down Sound volume when monitor is turned off

Tags: windows-7, audio, vlc-media-player

I have come to experience a pretty strange behavior. When I run VLC Player and I turn off my primary monitor to watch it on the secondary monitor, VLC Player turns down the volume. If I turn off my secondary monitor to watch it on my primary monitor, VLC does not turn down the volume. It also looks strange in the Volume mixer, as can be seen in the image I added Any idea, how to turn that behavior off?

**Edit:** Although I had the tags in correctly, I didn't write it in the text: Win7 Pro x64, SP1

[image]

Comment: Can't add a comment directly, but the settings change works for other things too, like skype calls or turning off the screen for WinAmp, windows is just weird as hell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to

> Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Sound > Communications tab

Select "Do Nothing"

[image]

Had this issue in a different application (Subsonic) and worked there.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Lately it's kinda random, so I don't know when I can tell if it worked.

Comment: I’m pretty sure that applies to *system sounds* (and master volume) as opposed to any specific application sounds. Besides, what does the monitor turning off have to do with making a call?

Answer (score 0):

This is REALLY weird bahaviour. If you can try some of these:

- Run VLC though the terminal and see if any relevant output is shown when you switch monitors
- Revert back to an older version of VLC (assuming you used it before without any issues)

Also, is this a laptop with VGA out or a desktop with a graphics card. There might a driver thing going on. Not quite sure, but its worth a look.